Why does my component disappear when using AnimatePresence of framer-motion?
I faced some weird bug that I don't understand when using framer-motion. I have the following code and when I click at the button, the h1 performs the corresponding animation as it should. However, if I click the button before the animation is finished, the component completely disappears.
import { useState } from "react";

import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function App() {
  const [boolean, setBoolean] = useState<boolean>(true);
  if (boolean) return <Component text="A" onClick={() => setBoolean(false)} />;
  else return <Component text="B" onClick={() => setBoolean(true)} />;
}

function Component({ text, onClick }: { text: string; onClick: () => void }) {
  return (
    <>
      <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
        <motion.h1
          key={text}
          initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
        >
          Title {text}
        </motion.h1>
      </AnimatePresence>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Button {text}</button>
    </>
  );
}

I would like the component to not disappear. I don't know why that happens and it is a strange behaviour.

I think by setting up exitBeforeEnter prop to false and adjusting the exit animation would work. Here's the updated code:
import { useState } from "react";
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function App() {
  const [boolean, setBoolean] = useState<boolean>(true);
  if (boolean) return <Component text="A" onClick={() => setBoolean(false)} />;
  else return <Component text="B" onClick={() => setBoolean(true)} />;
}

function Component({ text, onClick }: { text: string; onClick: () => void }) {
  return (
    <>
      <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter={false}>
        <motion.h1
          key={text}
          initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0 }} // Adjusted exit animation
        >
          Title {text}
        </motion.h1>
      </AnimatePresence>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Button {text}</button>
    </>
  );
}


It doesn't work and the exitBeforeEnter property is deprectated.
